# Magento 2 - Customer account custom tab not working

Tags: magento2, customer

In Magento 2, I try to add a new tab in My account page next to My Account, My Orders, My Wishlist, ...

I follow exactly this tutorial : 
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-tab-customer-account-magento-2.html

My new tab is created, but the route is not working, I have a 404 error when I click on this new tab.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: did you created routes.xml ?

Comment: @Pawan No I did not create because it is not specified in the tutorial. Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, you need to create it.

Comment: After adding routes.xml, is it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Create:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/routes.xml

with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="{routid}" frontName="{routid}">
            <module name="[Vendor]_[Module]" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Please replace `{routid}`,`[Vendor]` and `[Module]` name.

Comment: Thanks it works !

Comment: Glad to know...welcome ...:)

Comment: @Pawan What is {routid} in this will you please help me !

Comment: routid is the name by which you can access url, it could be same as module name. You can use `<route id="{moduleName}" frontName="{moduleName}">`.