# magento2 create menu when customer login

Tags: magento2.3

How can i create menu when customer login. My picture

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: please check : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-tab-customer-account-magento-2.html

Comment: thank for your help pawan!

Comment: welcome Hung...You also need to create routes.xml as per https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310490/magento-2-customer-account-custom-tab-not-working/310494?noredirect=1#comment451568_310494

Comment: you want to using custom module check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304060/85907